# rviz couldn't find executable

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I download rviz and I did `rosmake rviz`  but it gave me following error when I try `rosrun rviz rviz`

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named rviz below /home/mayara/groovy_workspace/sandbox/rviz
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/mayara/groovy_workspace/sandbox/rviz
[rosrun]   /home/mayara/groovy_workspace/sandbox/rviz/src/rviz
[rosrun]   /home/mayara/groovy_workspace/sandbox/rviz/src/python_bindings/rviz
```

Any idea ? I'm using ROS Groovy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62305/rviz-couldn%27t-find-executable/) by [Maytheewat](https://answers.ros.org/users/4743/maytheewat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 215 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In groovy, rviz uses catkin instead of rosmake, like any decent package does. Follow these steps to build it:

```
cd /home/mayara/groovy_workspace/sandbox/rviz
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
rosrun rviz rviz
```

The rviz binary will be /home/mayara/groovy_workspace/sandbox/rviz/devel/lib/rviz/rviz

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-07**:
For future readers: there is nothing "indecent" about using rosbuild. In some cases, there is no other option. In others, converting may not make sense yet.